# How to open websites in background and then close without interrupting flow of program using python?

Tags: opencv, python-3.7, os.system, python-webbrowser

I want to open a particular video in the background using python. For that, I have done the following coding

```
 chrome= "C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe %s"
 webbrowser.get(chrome).open_new("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AFNUeUed8Ro&ab_channel=NDTV")
 time.sleep(4)
 os.system("taskkill /im chrome.exe /f")**
```

but after opening the URL **program does not continue** until I manually close the site.
And if I beforehand open the chrome browser all works well. But that is not what I want.

I want to open it in the background because I only need audio as my project is for **blind people's** entertainment which opens sites using gestures only then close using the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you use Selenium instead of Webbrowser package as it has more functionality.

Install Selenium package using

```
pip install selenium
```

Download Chrome webdriver which matches your version of Chrome from

https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads

Place the driver .exe file where you python script is located

Try this script

```
import selenium
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 3)
visible = EC.visibility_of_element_located

browser.get('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AFNUeUed8Ro&ab_channel=NDTV')
wait.until(visible((By.ID, "video-title")))
browser.find_element_by_id("video-title").click()
browser.minimize_window()
time.sleep(7)
browser.quit()
```

Don't use time.sleep() in Opencv capture loop because it blocks the capture. If you want to use time delays consider using separate thread.
Look at

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_multithreading.htm

Comment: I will surely try this approach. Thanks for the answer and link too.